# Using C++ with Tizen libraries

Tags: c++, callback, tizen

I'm a C++ developer new to Tizen.  I've gone through all of the (native) sample code and it appears to make heavy use of callbacks.

Since you can't (easily) pass member functions in place of callbacks (unless static), that makes it much more difficult to use C++ in place of C.

Is there an advantage to using C++ (with static methods for all CB) - or should I stick with C and use long convoluted function names to organize the various functions.  (Sort of like a namespace)

Is there another solution?

Comment: I'd say there is an advantage, because the cast from `void*` is confined to one particular location - the `static` function that's bound to the particular callback. Remember that you can pass `this` via the `ctx` parameter to a C callback and piggyback to a "normal" C++ member function this way.

Comment: Daniel: The Tizen libraries perform the callbacks, so I can't make them pass a this parameter (with bind).  I'm not sure what you mean about confining void* to one location.

Answer (score 1):

The "user_data" argument of callback is what you need to utilize. Example: [device_changed_cb typedef](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=/dev-guide/2.4/org.tizen.native.mobile.apireference/group__CAPI__SYSTEM__DEVICE__CALLBACK__MODULE.html#ga42bc695eaac93c771d89f2c0877a1071). You may use this "user_data" as "this class".

I'd suggest the following pseudo-c++ code:

```
class X {
   void member_func(type, value);
   static member_func_cb(type, value, void *user_data) {
      class X *xptr = (class *X) user_data;
      xptr->member_func(type, value);
   };
   ...
      register_callback(member_func_cb, this);
   ...
};
```

With a proper macro definition, you can avoid redefining *_cb functions in a class as well.

Comment: The parameters for the callbacks have been defined by the Tizen library, so I can't change them.  But I understand what you are suggesting (CB to a static method which calls the instance method)

Comment: Yes, I'm specifically talking about the parameters for the callbacks of Tizen. The last parameter, "user_data", is supposed to be used as in my example. If you look at Tizen native API documents, you will see that we have "user_data" parameter in the callback definition.

The deviced-callback in the link above allows you to do:

     device_add_callback (device_callback_e type, device_changed_cb callback, void *user_data)



I've designed a few native API sets of Tizen and that was my purpose if my memory serves right :)